# Undefined variable error when doing calculations

Tags: php, laravel

I have a web application that I'm rebuilding in Laravel for a cleaning company.

1) I pass in the paramaters to the URL route

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/book?bed_range=1&bath_range=1&percentage_range=0&duration_range=
```

2) It does calculations:

```
    $bedroomCostFactor = [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150];
    $bathroomCostFactor = [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100];
    $percentageFactor = [0, 5, 15, 10, 20];    

    if (isset($bed_range) && !empty($bed_range)) {

    if ($bed_range == 1) {
        $bed_cost = $bedroomCostFactor[0];
    } else if ($bed_range == 2){
        $bed_cost = $bedroomCostFactor[1];
    } else if ($bed_range == 3){
        $bed_cost = $bedroomCostFactor[2];
    } else if ($bed_range == 4){
        $bed_cost = $bedroomCostFactor[3];
    } else if ($bed_range == 5){
        $bed_cost = $bedroomCostFactor[4];
    } else if ($bed_range == 6){
        $bed_cost = $bedroomCostFactor[5];
    }
    }

    if(isset($bath_range) && !empty($bath_range)) {
    if ($bath_range == 1) {
        $bath_cost = $bathroomCostFactor[0];
    } else if ($bath_range == 2){
        $bath_cost = $bathroomCostFactor[1];
    } else if ($bath_range == 3){
        $bath_cost = $bathroomCostFactor[2];
    } else if ($bath_range == 4){
        $bath_cost = $bathroomCostFactor[3];
    } else if ($bath_range == 5){
        $bath_cost = $bathroomCostFactor[4];
    } else if ($bath_range == 6){
        $bath_cost = $bathroomCostFactor[5];
    }
    }

    if(isset($percentage_range) && !empty($percentage_range)) {

    if ($percentage_range == 0) {
        $percentage_cost = $percentageFactor[0];
    } else if ($percentage_range == 5){
        $percentage_cost = $percentageFactor[1];
    } else if ($percentage_range == 15){
        $percentage_cost = $percentageFactor[2];
    } else if ($percentage_range == 10){
        $percentage_cost = $percentageFactor[3];
    } else if ($percentage_range == 20){
        $percentage_cost = $percentageFactor[4];
    }

}

$subtotal = "100.00";

$tax = number_format($subtotal * .0725, 2);
$total = $subtotal + $tax;
$discount = number_format(($subtotal * $percentage_cost) / 100, 2);
```

For some reason, when I migrate the code to Laravel, it no longer works and it starts saying variables like $discount and $percentage_cost are undefined.

In my previous application the calculations run just fine like you'd expect. Why isn't it working in Laravel?

Comment: Where is this code in your Laravel app? Is this contained in a controller method, a service, or what?

Comment: Are you sure `$percentage_cost` is always defined as a result of your conditional statements? It's possible that `$percentage_range` is a value other than 0, 5, 10, 15, or 20.

Comment: The code is contained in the view.

Comment: Yes I believe it is always defined since I always pass in the $percentage_range which calculates the $percentage_cost

Comment: `For some reason, when I migrate the code to Laravel`. Where is the new code? I dont see any calculations actually.

Comment: There is no new code, it's the same code

Comment: I dont see any calculations.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['bed_range']) || isset($_POST['bath_range']) || isset($_POST['percentage_range']) || isset($_POST['duration_range'])) {
        $bed_range = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'bed_range');
        $bath_range = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'bath_range');
        $percentage_range = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'percentage_range');
        $duration_range = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'duration_range');
        }

Comment: else if (isset($_GET['bed_range']) || isset($_GET['bath_range']) || isset($_GET['percentage_range']) || isset($_GET['duration_range'])) {
        $bed_range = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'bed_range');
        $bath_range = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'bath_range');
        $percentage_range = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'percentage_range');
        $duration_range = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'duration_range');
        }

Comment: That code is in the controller

Comment: Where and how in the above calculations is `duration_range` used?

Comment: Also, in the above `$subtotal` is defined explicitly with a string value at "100.00"  - is that simply for the question and is actually calculated by adding values `$bed_cost` and `$bath_cost`?

Comment: duration range is not really used unless declared by the user

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove the if condition

```
if(isset($percentage_range) && !empty($percentage_range)) {
```